# Is scrolling counted as an activity?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I would like to know if user scroll (for instance, when reading a blog post) is counted as an activity (meaning: that user won't be counted in the bounce rate).

Comment: Blexy's plugin is pretty awesome but if you want some other ideas on ways to think about scroll tracking check out Justin Curtoni's (Google's Analytics Advocate) post on it. http://cutroni.com/blog/2012/02/21/advanced-content-tracking-with-google-analytics-part-1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a plugin like - [Scroll Depth](http://parsnip.io/scroll-depth/) and create event-based goals based on how far the user scrolls.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe so, activity is when a tracking pixel is created which occurs only when you call a GA function, like `_trackPageview` or `_trackEvent`.

You can watch the Network tab of your developer tools to see when one is created to make sure exactly how analytics are being recorded on your site.